Commentaries relevant to doubled phrases in Aleinu
The Aleinu prayer contains many instances of doubled phrases - where the same idea is expressed twice (or two very similar ideas are expressed) with different language. Here are three in the first sentence:

לְשַׁבֵּֽחַ לַאֲדוֹן הַכֹּל / לָתֵת גְּדֻלָּה לְיוֹצֵר בְּרֵאשִׁית - to praise the Master of all / to ascribe greatness to the Creator of the [world in the] beginning

שֶׁלֺּא עָשָֽׂנוּ כְּגוֹיֵי הָאֲרָצוֹת / וְלֺא שָׂמָֽנוּ כְּמִשְׁפְּחוֹת הָאֲדָמָה - has not made us like the nations of the lands / and has not positioned us like the families of the earth

חֶלְקֵֽנוּ כָּהֶם / וְגוֹרָלֵֽנוּ כְּכָל הֲמוֹנָם - our portion like theirs / nor our lot like that of all their multitudes


I am aware that this pattern exists in Tanach as well. I think I've seen it in Tehillim and Mishlei, at least. I realize that it could be interpreted as merely a mechanism for poetic emphasis.

Do any commentaries on Aleinu discuss the use of this pattern there, in particular?

Are there any articles about this pattern in general that could shed light on its use in Aleinu?

Is there a standard term for this pattern in Parshanut literature?



The openings of Zikhronot and Shofarot are structured similarly

Rav Chaim Kanievsky zatzal authored a commentary on Aleinu, which can be downloaded from this site . I have checked the first of your questions therein.
He maintains that “Master of all” refers to Hashem in His attribute of giving the Torah. (page 21, in Biurim 1) whereas “Creator of the [world in the] beginning” refers to Hashem in His attribute of Creator in the fist 6 days of creation (page 25, in Biurim 6).

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

The phenomenon that you describe is a part of a much larger group of patterns called Biblical parallelism. A book by Adele Berlin "The dynamics of Biblical parallelism" is considered a good study.
